# Smooth solutions to the Neumann problem defined on the closure of the domain

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde, regularity

Does the Neumann-problem for the Laplace equation on a smooth bounded domain $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^{3}$ with smooth boundary data $g$ such that
\begin{equation}
\int_{\partial \Omega}g \, d \sigma = 0
\end{equation}
have a solution in $C^{\infty}(\overline{\Omega})$?

By $C^{\infty}(\overline{\Omega})$, I mean that the solution can be extended to a smooth function defined on an open set containing $\overline{\Omega}$. I am also interested in the same problem posed on exterior domains. I would be very thankful for references.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2940989/need-good-reference-or-a-proof-on-regularity-of-solution-to-neumann-problem) for the first step in proving such a result.